# Pass value from url request with Django generic detail view

Tags: python, django, web, server-side

From the GenericList, when clicking on one I redirect towards

```
    url(r'^machine/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MachineDetailView.as_view(), name='machine-detail'),
```

Where

```
class MachineDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Awg
    template_name = 'gui/machine_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'last_entry'
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

However what I need is to fetch AWG records where machine.id is foreign key in AWG's.

In my mind it would look like that:

```
class MachineDetailView(DetailView):
    last_entry = Awg.objects.filter(machine_id=Machine.objects.filter(id=pk).first()).first()
    model = Awg
    template_name = 'gui/machine_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'last_entry'
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

That doesn't work because I don't know how to get that `pk` that is in the url requested. 
Apologies if noob, I did try to look in django docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_object(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object), and make a query that returns that object. you can obtain the `pk` parameter from the url pattern through `self.kwargs` which is a dictionary that contains the URL parameters:

```
class MachineDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Awg
    template_name = 'gui/machine_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'last_entry'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Awg.objects.filter(
            machine_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        ).latest('timestamp')
```

Comment: That does work. No way I would've ever found this on my own. Cheers!